# Installing ubuntu fails due to all usb ports has usb 3 or above with an xhci error

Tags: system-installation, usb, 22.04, xhci-hcd

```
xhci_hcd 0000:24:00:00.0: init 000:24:00.0 fail -16
```

I am trying to install ubuntu to my computer. Hovewer my computer only has usb 3 ports. Therefore, there are xhci routines and can install ubuntu to my computer. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You've provided few Ubuntu product/release details; nor clues as to your architecture of hardware, are you hoping we guess?   Why not just tell us?  (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server? Desktop? a *flavor*? what architecture? which ISO as there are many; 20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2... 20.04.6 etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Hi, this is not about will it work or not. It is working. After I select "Try or install ubuntu" this error message appears and nothing more happens. This issue arises because the usb3 does not bypass xhci like usb 2.

Comment: We can't help much as per my first comment, we don't know what Ubuntu product (Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop, a Ubuntu *flavor*), what architecture?  what release of that *unstated* product (and there are multiple ISO choices for some product/release combinations too) thus don't currently know what you're using.  Is this Ubuntu Desktop 23.04 for example?  if it is, are you using the *primary* ISO/installer for Ubuntu Desktop 23.04? or the *legacy* ISO/installer?  (selected at download), or is it Ubuntu 23.04 Server?, or is it... etc (the two 23.04 Desktop ISOs differ at Try/Install code)

Comment: It is Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop.

Comment: Please correct your question then (you state 20.04 there, but didn't specify if desktop or server, nor if 20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2,... etc).  The 22.04 in your last comment *contradicts* details in your question thus far.  Please correct your question.  *The upgrade level (.1, .2, .. .6) provide clues as to kernel stack on media & more which is very detail on live or install questions*

Comment: I updated from 20.04 to 22.04.

Comment: Thank you for updating & clarifying some details; but you've still not said which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Product; as both Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server have different kernel defaults, let alone Desktop having ISOs with 5.15, 5.19 or 6.2 kernels available (ie. 22.04, 22.04.1 & 22.04.2). As it's not yet installed, being specific as to what you're trying to boot & install is extremely useful. The kernel changes kernel modules (aka *drivers*) and thus far I see 3 possible kernel stacks (on different ISOs) which you've not said which you got the error on.